# Qt Creator - SelectedDate() doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt, selected

I am looking for help with `SelectedDate()` function (from `QCalendarWidget` class) in Qt Creator. Im building my first program and to end i need to know how to use this function correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq8LQ.jpg

Comment: use `ui->calendarWidget->selectedDate();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post your code/error messages as images. Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot mr.eyllanesc! <3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Label use QDateEdit to get a calender popup.

```
QDateEdit *dateEdit=new QDateEdit();
dateEdit->setCalendarPopup(true);

QDate date=dateEdit->date();//Selected Date
```

Setting calender popup to true gives you a calender widget where you can select the date which will be displayed on QDateEdit.